# htaccess cannot compile regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I got this error message:

`RewriteRule`: Cannot compile regular expression

```
'([0-9]+)/((?!thumb)[A-Za-z0-9_-\\s]+)\\.([A-Za-z0-9_-\\s]+)$'
```

And the code where this problem occurred is:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/((?!thumb)[A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)$ ../members/download.php?u=$1/$2.$3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your character set class, you have:

```
_-\s
```

which means, in this context, to capture all characters with ASCII values between that of `_` and `\s`. They are as follows:

1. `_` is at 95
2. `\s` is 32

And, this range is thus, invalid; leading to the error.

Put the `-` at the end of the class to make the pattern work:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/((?!thumb)[A-Za-z0-9_\s-]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_\s-]+)$ ../members/download.php?u=$1/$2.$3
```